# Retrieving original class types from anonymous classes

Tags: scala, reflection

Given a class with an empty constructor and a var:

```
class MyClass() {
  var myVar: Int = 0
}
```

When the class is instantiated with a closure, this yields an object with the underlying type of an anonymous class rather than MyClass:

```
// getClass yields type my.package.MainClass$$anonfun$1$anonfun$apply...
val myNewClassInstance: MyClass = new MyClass() { myVar = 2}
```

Is it possible to retrieve the original class type MyClass using reflection and  the object myNewClassInstance, in order to create new object instances from it?

Comment: actually, this anonymous class extends the original one

Comment: can you please elaborate on why do you need that at all? I can think of at least two ways of how to extract particular type from your type hierarchy, but probably your whole task can be done with easier approach.

Comment: I have a method that takes Class[T] as input. I'd like to create new instances of T via reflection using a default constructor that takes no parameters (or throw an exception if the user submits a class that lacks one). The problem is that anonymous classes are assigned their own  constructor that takes a parameter, causing these classes to fail validation even though the user-class itself would be valid if only the original class type (and its empty constructor) could be accessed. So I need some way to separate the anonymous class types from the regular ones, and restore their original types.

Comment: @Aeris130 but how can you decide that it was not user's intention to pass anonymous class (maybe user had overridden some methods and expect class with such override to be created)? Please mention me using `@`, so I can see notification about your response.

Comment: @Aivean Hadn't thought of that, I guess my real problem is to find whatever no-arguments constructor was used to instantiate myNewClassInstance, and invoke it again through reflection. But since it's no longer available through .getConstructors in the anonymous class, I'm not sure how to go about it.

Comment: @Aeris130, probably you can keep it simple: instantiate the class only if it has default no-argument constructor and throw exception otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a superclass:

```
scala> class MyClass
defined class MyClass

scala> val a = new MyClass { val c = 5 }
a: MyClass{val c: Int} = $anon$1@48cf768c

scala> a.getClass
res0: Class[_ <: MyClass] = class $anon$1

scala> a.getClass.getSuperclass
res1: Class[?0] forSome { type ?0 >: ?0; type ?0 <: MyClass } = class MyClass
```

Comment: That works. Is there a way to tell which class objects that need to have their type restored this way? isSynthetic and isAnonymous doesn't seem to work.

Comment: there should be a smarter way, but what first came in mind is checking the name for "$anon$"